# ip route show missing routes

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing

I have a node running ub18 kernel version 5.4 with `ifplugd` at version 0.28-19.2

I run the following command: `ip route replace default metric 99 proto kernel nexthop via <DG1_IP> dev eth0 onlink nexthop via <DG2_IP> dev eth1 onlink`

but the show command does not show this route

```
~ ip route show
default proto bgp metric 20
    nexthop via inet6 fe80::eef4:bbff:fefd:aa74 dev eth1 weight 1
    nexthop via inet6 fe80::eef4:bbff:fefd:a9f3 dev eth0 weight 1
```

What I expect to see:

```
~ ip route show
default  proto zebra  metric 20
    nexthop via inet6 fe80::eef4:bbff:fefd:aa74 dev eth1 weight 1
    nexthop via inet6 fe80::eef4:bbff:fefd:a9f3 dev eth0 weight 1
default  proto static  metric 99
    nexthop via <DG1_IP>  dev eth1 weight 1 onlink
    nexthop via <DG2_IP>  dev eth0 weight 1 onlink
```

This behavior started when we mistakenly upgraded our ub18 nodes to use kernel version 5.4 instead of 4.15

Comment: testing with iproute 5.18 and kernel 5.17.x works as you're intending (except `proto static` should be used instead of `proto kernel` to get static in the result). So you could try with a more recent Ubuntu release and see what happens. Also your example lacks some minor information (eg: `-6` to `ip route show` or non-explained `bgp` vs `zebra` in the data) so I might not have reproduced exactly the same.

Comment: Also in case it's caused by ifplugd (which I didn't use in my very basic test), you should keep an `ip -ts monitor` command running around to have logs.